# wordpress Footer css doesn't work

Tags: css, wordpress, footer

Footer css appears right on every page except `single.php` page.. The browsers reads on every page in css:

```
    #sidebar + #wrapper + #footer {
margin-left:18em;
}
```

but at full post page

```
#sidebar + #wrapper + #footer {
margin-left: 18em;
}
```

it doesn't work

**Footer css**

```
/* Footer */

    #sidebar + #wrapper + #footer {
        margin-left: 18em;
    }

        @media screen and (max-width: 1280px) {

            #sidebar + #wrapper + #footer {
                margin-left: 0;
            }

        }

    #footer > .inner a {
        border-bottom-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15);
    }

        #footer > .inner a:hover {
            border-bottom-color: transparent;
        }

    #footer > .inner .menu {
        font-size: 0.8em;
        color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15);
    }

    #header + #wrapper + #footer > .inner {
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
```

**footer.php**

```
        <!-- Footer -->
            <footer id="footer" class="wrapper style1-alt">
                <div class="inner">
                    <ul class="menu">

                    <?php if ( ! dynamic_sidebar( 'footer_sidebar' ) ) : ?>
                        <li>&copy; Untitled. All rights reserved.</li>
                    <?php endif; ?> 


                    </ul>
                </div>
            </footer>

        <!-- Scripts -->

<?php wp_footer(); ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

**single.php**

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

        <!-- Wrapper -->
            <div id="wrapper">

                <!-- One -->
                    <section id="one" class="wrapper style2 spotlights">

                    <?php while(have_posts())  : the_post(); ?>
                        <section>
                            <div class="content">
                                <div class="sin_content">
                                    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                                        <?php echo do_shortcode("[easy_image_gallery]"); 
                                      remove_filter( 'the_content', 'easy_image_gallery_append_to_content' ); ?>
                        </div>
                                    <?php the_content(); ?>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </section>
                    <div class="wordpress_commentss-hd">
                        <div class="wordpress_commentss">
                            <?php comments_template(); ?>  
                        </div>
                    </div>  
                    <?php endwhile; ?>


                    </section>
            </div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

why it doesn't work on full posts pages while works fine on other pages?

Comment: share the code until this is meaningles

Comment: HAve you tried using `#sidebar, #wrapper, #footer` ?

Comment: This uses the adjacent css selector (+) and will only work if the sidebar, wrapper and footer immediately follow each other as siblings. I guess single.php might be missing one of these or have some elements between the selected elements.

Comment: I have added the code, please, look through it. Thanks.

Comment: Post the rendered HTML, not the PHP

Comment: @j08691 seems this difficult to understand

Comment: I see a #footer and a #wrapper but no #sidebar, that might be missing in single.php or is it included in get_header()? Posting the rendered HTML would help idd.

Comment: I have sidebar in header.php and it works right on other pages..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haha, found it :) You have one too many closing div's. Remove the one in single.php between:

```
  remove_filter( 'the_content', 'easy_image_gallery_append_to_content' ); ?>
</div> <--- That one!
  <?php the_content(); ?>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, you are very helpful, you saved my day :))